# Cannot upload app to google play console, App was signed in debug Mode

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, keystore

As the question says I am not able to upload an APK generated and signed by Unity. It gives me the error saying that the app is signed I debug mode.
Things I have already tried

1. check if the APK is actually signed by the upload key
2. Check the AndroidManifest of the APK using the `aapt` tool to check for the debuggable flag set (it wasn't there)
3. Use Monodevelop to set the app configuration to release
4. Build the app from Android studio

I can also see that my apkj is signed with the same key as my upload certificate on google play console

[image]

However none of these things work, Google play console still thinks that the app was signed in debug mode

Any idea how I can fix this ?

Comment: I don't know with unity but when apk singed using Android Studio then `Build Type` should be `release` when creating singed apk, thrs two type one is `debug` and second is `release`

Comment: answer to your question https://answers.unity.com/questions/1096300/hello-i-have-a-big-probleme.html

Comment: @AbdulKawee I am already doing that

Comment: @BhaveshRangani I am using the release configuration to create the signed APK , verified it thrice

Comment: Did you check the V2 signature checkbox when building with Android Studio?

Comment: yup I did check that

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Development Build box checked? Check [this](http://answers.unity.com/answers/557500/view.html) link.

[image]

I hope this helps you :)

Comment: Yup I am not checking the development build box

Comment: tried the steps on this video , still cant upload it, this is getting crazy :/

Comment: Yes, it's crazy. Please see this [link](https://unitycoder.com/blog/2015/05/04/building-apk-with-release-mode/). I know you signed your file; But check all the steps. if I find other ways, I will send for you.

Comment: I am pretty sure I have followed all the steps, I can see with `apksigner` that my apk is infact signed with the key as my upload certificate in google play console. I have edited my question with a screenshot of it

Comment: if you create a new unity project and publish it on Google play service, this error is still showing?